# Use Platform Event or Streaming API?

Tags: lightning, streaming-api, platform-event

I am new to Salesforce Platform event and streaming API topics. After riffling through some documentation and getting enough confused, asking out for help here if anyone can suggest me the best approach for my use case.

On the opportunity lightning detail page, we want to embed various lightning components and wants data to be updated on one more lightning components based on an event on the other component in Opportunity details page. Hope my questions is clear.

Comment: All components are on the same page?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal yes

Comment: I would think you just need [Application Events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_application.htm) here. In fact if it's about updating the view, you can just utilize [`force:refreshView`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:refreshView/documentation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> On the opportunity lightning detail page, we want to embed various lightning components and wants data to be updated on one more lightning components based on an event on the other component in Opportunity details page.

If this is what you are looking for, then you don't really need Platform Event or Streaming API here. You can incorporate this just by using [Application Events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_application.htm). So one of your component fires the event and other components handle that event thus refreshing their data.

Or even simpler, once you know the processing is complete in your component and that data has been updated in the backend and that your other components can be refreshed to reflect that data, you can just use [`force:refreshView`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:refreshView/documentation) to refresh the whole view.

Comment: Spot on. I was about to answer same

Comment: @PranayJaiswal reminds me of "great minds think alike " ;)

Comment: @JayantDas are application event valid when we hv to pass data between different lightning applications?

Comment: @ShivaAchukatla based on the format of SFSE, your question categorizes as a new question. Also I am not really sure about this, because I would think application events are handled by the framework within a single app and not cross app.